# file "mysql" unix executable file inside MAMP/Library/bin

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have accidentally deleted the file "mysql" which is a unix executable file inside MAMP/Library/bin folder using "rm" command on the terminal. My question is is there any way to get back that file without reinstalling MAMP? or do I have to?
Please help. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply [download the MAMP zip](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html), extract it, and then copy the "mysql" file  into the correct folder. That said, make sure you are getting the same version of MAMP (or at least, of MySQL).

For the future, you could change the owner of the mamp directory (and files) to root, and set the permissions to 0755. This would only allow the root user to delete files, but everyone could read and execute. Something like this:

```
> su root
Password: 
> chown -R root:root /path/to/mamp
> chmod -R 0755 /path/to/mamp
```

Note that you will need to be the root user to do this, so enter your password after that first line.